# How to write a .csv file on a network location?

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-4, csv, export-to-csv

I am currently writing a .csv to client browser using Response object, which was/is a fairly easy job.

But now the requirement has been changed to create this file at a network location from where any time the job will pick it.

I am not sure how can I achieve this, any suggestions would be helpful.

Existing Code:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + GenerateFileName(publishToViewModel[0].ProjectId));
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter();
try
{
    string CSVFriendlyData = this.GetCSV(publishToViewModel);
    writer.Write(CSVFriendlyData);
    Response.Write(writer.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since it is hard to guarantee that a write to a network file will be successful (your old file might still be there, and the timed job might have a lock on it, etc) it's a good idea to build a mechanism that will retry writing to the file several times.

```
void WriteToNetworkFile()
{
  int retries = 3;    
  while(retries > 0)
  {
     if(tryWriteFile())
     {
        break;
     } 
     retries--;

     // you could add a timeout here to make sure your attempts are a little more
     //spaced out.
     //it could be in the form of a Thread.Sleep, or you could extract a method and
     //call it using a timer.

     if(retries < 1)
     {
        //log that we failed to write the file and gave up on trying.
     }
  }
}    
protected void tryWriteFile()
{
   try
   {
     //you could pass this path as a parameter too.
     var fileLoc = "\\server\folder\file.ext";

     //open and obtain read/write lock on the file
     //using FileMode.CreateNew will ensure that a new file is created.
     //alternatively, you can use FileMosw.Create to create a new file
     //or overwrite the old file if it is there.
     using (var fs = File.Open(fileLoc, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
     {
          var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
          sw.Write("file contents go here");
          sw.Flush();
          sw.Close();
          return true;
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       //you might want to log why the write failed here.
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP if you add some explanation to your code.

Comment: i'm on it :P your edit made me lose the explanation i was adding initially. got butterfingers and clicked refresh.